# Java - Reading in signed integers from a file

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, readfile

I am trying to read in 10 signed integers from a file into an array and for some reason, it is not happening and I am not getting any errors at compile and runtime. I just wanted a second pair of eyes to look over this and see what I might be missing.

The test file is "input.txt" and contains: -1, 4, 32, 0, -12, 2, 30, 1, -3, -32

Here is my code:

```
  public void readFromFile(String filename)
  {
     try {
        File f = new File(filename);
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(f);
        String nextLine;
        int[] testAry = new int[10];
        int i = 0;

        while (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
           testAry[i] = scan.nextInt();
           i++;
        }
     }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
           System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
        }
  }
```

Comment: Is this the entire program? It looks fine to me.... also testAry is a local variable and you're not returning it so what exactly does this method do?

Comment: Just reads in the input into an array and I need to use that array in some other functions later in the program. What happens is in Debug Mode, it hits the while-statement for the first time and skips it and breaks from the function.

Comment: That's a local array I don't see anywhere where you save that information somewhere that's not local to the function, also if those are commas you need to change the delimiter Scanner uses.

Comment: This is the line of code I am trying to run after the file if read in: `int[] inputArray = new int[10];
inputArray = hmwk.readFromFile("input.txt");
hmwk.algorithmOne(inputArray);`

Comment: But where does inputArray get populated? Also if the hasNextInt() loop isn't running its because 23, isn't an int because of the comma, change the delimiter to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the default delimiter on the Scanner object.

try using the delimiter ive got in the line useDelimiter(\\s*,\\s*").  Its regex to split up your the input from the file by a comma.

```
 try {
            File f = new File("input.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
            scan.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
            String nextLine; //left it in even tho you are not using it
            int[] testAry = new int[10];
            int i = 0;

            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                testAry[i] = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println(testAry[i]);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be throwing another exception you are not catching

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

the int scanned from the input Throws:

```
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

Or you could just go old school and use a buffered reader to verify you are getting data

```
try{

  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);

  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;

  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

    System.out.println (strLine);
  }
  in.close();
  }catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
   }
```